# AR scanning object big object (recognition)

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, virtual-reality

Any tips how to make AR with some big objects? Like building, car or kitchen?
I already used it Vuforia. But Vuforia is only for small object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like ARCore for Android or ARKit for iOS.

Comment: neither ARCore nor ARKit have object recognition (small or big). iOS only has image recognition with ARKit 1.5 release.